# Python enumerate for a datetime list

Tags: python, datetime, enumerate

I want to move from the "i=0 ... i=i+1" construct to use Python enumerate. I'm having trouble with a list of datetime values. I understand that datetime objects (themselves) are not iterable (if that's the correct word) but I would think that a normal "list" of these objects would be iterable/enumerable. I must be wrong but I don't know why.

My original code:

```
import datetime

BIASList = [1.3719, 0.9861, 0.0782, 1.9248, 0.7429]

dList = [datetime.date(2017, 1, 19),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 20),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 21),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 22),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 23)]

i = 0
for d in dList:
    dom = d.strftime("%d")
    print(d, '   i = ', i, 'BIAS = ',
          BIASList[i],  'dom = ', dom)
    i = i + 1
```

produced

```
2017-01-19    i =  0 BIAS =  1.3719 dom =  19
2017-01-20    i =  1 BIAS =  0.9861 dom =  20
2017-01-21    i =  2 BIAS =  0.0782 dom =  21
2017-01-22    i =  3 BIAS =  1.9248 dom =  22
2017-01-23    i =  4 BIAS =  0.7429 dom =  23
```

My revised attempt at using enumerate was

```
import datetime

BIASList = [1.3719, 0.9861, 0.0782, 1.9248, 0.7429]

dList = [datetime.date(2017, 1, 19),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 20),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 21),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 22),
         datetime.date(2017, 1, 23)]

i = 0
for count, d in dList:
    dom = d.strftime("%d")
    print(d, '   i = ', i, 'count = ', count, 'BIAS = ',
          BIASList[count],  'dom = ', dom)
    i = i + 1
```

The error was listed as

```
  File ...\untitled0.py:21 in <module>
    for count, d in dList:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable datetime.date object
```

Comment: Uh... you didn't actually use `enumerate` anywhere in your attempt to use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `enumerate` with `dList` as the argument.  `enumerate` will give you an iterable of tuples (the index and the original item), which you can use to produce the same `i` as in your original code without needing to actually initialize and increment `i`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(dList):
    dom = d.strftime("%d")
    print(d, '   i = ', i, 'BIAS = ',
          BIASList[i],  'dom = ', dom)
```

If you're just trying to iterate over two lists in parallel, an even easier option is `zip`:

```
for d, b in zip(dList, BIASList):
    dom = d.strftime("%d")
    print(f"{d}  BIAS = {b}  dom = {dom}")
```

and if you want to print that `i` for some other reason you can combine `enumerate` and `zip`:

```
for i, (d, b) in enumerate(zip(dList, BIASList)):
    dom = d.strftime("%d")
    print(f"{d}  i = {i}  BIAS = {b}  dom = {dom}")
```